# unknown error when i run my application

Tags: java, android, jersey

When i run my application in android studio the message error display me this error:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'.
```

> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: org/glassfish/jersey/client/ClientProperties.class

I do not know how resolve this error.

I think this error depends on this code:

```
import com.github.irobson.jgenderize.model.NameGender;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Locale;
import javax.ws.rs.client.Client;
import javax.ws.rs.client.ClientBuilder;
import javax.ws.rs.client.WebTarget;
import javax.ws.rs.core.GenericType;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;

public class DefaultGenderize implements Genderize, Serializable {

    private final Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient();

    private static final String GENDERIZE_IO_API_URL = "https://api.genderize.io/";

    public NameGender getGender(String name, Locale locale) {
        WebTarget target = client.target(GENDERIZE_IO_API_UR`enter code here`L).queryParam("name", name);
        if (locale != null) {
            target = target.queryParam("country_id", locale.getCountry());
            target = target.queryParam("language_id", locale.getLanguage());
        }
        return target.request(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_TYPE).get(NameGender.class);
    }

    public List<NameGender> getGenders(String[] names, Locale locale) {
        GenericType<List<NameGender>> genericType = new GenericType<List<NameGender>>() {
        };

        WebTarget target = client.target(GENDERIZE_IO_API_URL);
        for (int i = 0; i < names.length; i++) {
            target = target.queryParam(String.format("name[%d]", i), names[i]);
        }
        if (locale != null) {
            target = target.queryParam("country_id", locale.getCountry());
            target = target.queryParam("language_id", locale.getLanguage());
        }
        return target.request(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_TYPE).get(genericType);
    }

    public NameGender getGender(String name) {
        return getGender(name, null);
    }

    public List<NameGender> getGenders(String... names) {
        return getGenders(names, null);
    }
}
```

or from some library.

Comment: Post your `build.gradle`

Comment: In this link paste it build.gradle [link](http://pastebin.com/peBggyVU)

Comment: remove `compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.0'`

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya don't resolve

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya okey i try it

Comment: Actually update your SDK Manager

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya the application run but i recive this error:java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyClientBuilder

Comment: Use `Jersey 2.22.1` jar ,https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/user-guide.html  Then `Clean-rebuild-restart-Sync` your project .

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya yes yes, one moment :)

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya I received this Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: javax/inject/Inject.class

Comment: use `compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'` & Then `Clean-Rebuild-Restart-Sync`

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya I am trying

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya multidex does not work, 
I get the same error

Comment: Comment out `multiDexEnabled true`  & `compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'` And make sure you updated Support repository SDK

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya does not work

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya i add this : compile ('org.glassfish.jersey.core:jersey-client:2.22.1') {
        exclude group: 'javax.inject', module: 'javax.inject'

    } and the error change. The actually error is Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: org/glassfish/hk2/internal/ActiveDescriptorBuilderImpl$BuiltActiveDescriptor.class

Comment: Very strange case . `libs/jersey-client-` and  `'org.glassfish.jersey.core:jersey-client:2.22.1` are same probably

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya try to comment the libs/jersey-client?

Comment: Yes yes .For testing case . `duplicate entry` happen same type library calling once more .

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya does not work

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya leaving only compile files ( ' libs / jersey - client - 2.22.1.jar ' )
I get this error: [link](http://pastebin.com/ECkKBrev)

Comment: Call `compile 'org.glassfish.jersey.core:jersey-client:2.0-m04'`

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya i add this compile ('org.glassfish.jersey.core:jersey-client:2.0-m04') {
        exclude group: 'javax.inject', module: 'javax.inject'
    } and return this error Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: org/jvnet/tiger_types/Lister.class

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya no, but sorry i can't send you a demo code.

Comment: Okay . As your wish .

Answer (score 1):

> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException:
>   java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry:
>   org/glassfish/jersey/client/ClientProperties.class

You have multiple `appcompat-v7` ,That's why have problem .

**Don't**

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.0'
```

**Do**

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3'
```

**Edit**

```
 apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.0"
    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true

    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    //  compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'javax.ws.rs:javax.ws.rs-api:2.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.0.0'
    //   compile 'javax.websocket:javax.websocket-all:1.1'
    // compile files('libs/hk2-api-2.2.0-b21.jar')
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
    //  compile 'org.glassfish.jersey:project:2.22.1'
    // compile 'org.glassfish.jersey.core:jersey-client:2.0-m04'
    compile files('libs/jersey-client-2.19.jar')
}
```

Comment: @ChintanRathod Ji . Sorry for late answer . But i never copy your answer .#MoveAheadGDG

Answer (score 0):

I can see two "support v7" dependencies. Remove one of them.

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.0'
```

Result

```
dependencies {
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'javax.ws.rs:javax.ws.rs-api:2.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
    compile files('libs/jersey-client-2.19.jar')
}
```